# Querying for all files above a certain size with mediastore

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm trying to query for every file in an android device using the mediastore API. Is there a shorter way of writing the `selection` string to include all the files in the device without having to write each for the Audio,Video,Images and NON_MEDIA? Also,how can I make the query,in addition,to get only the files of above a particular file size.

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

// every column, although that is huge waste, you probably need
// BaseColumns.DATA (the path) only.
String[] projection = null;

// exclude media files, they would be here also.
String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
        + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_NONE + "OR" + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE 
         + " OR "
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO + " OR "
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;
String[] selectionArgs = null; // there is no ? in selection so null here

String sortOrder = null; // unordered
Cursor allFiles = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a shorter way of writing the selection string to include all
> the files in the device without having to write each for the
> Audio,Video,Images and NON_MEDIA?

yes, MediaStore.Files
This is how I achieved (below code is in kotlin)

```
 private suspend fun getAllFiles(context : Context) : List<AllFiles>{
    return   withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        val fileCollection = mutableListOf<AllFiles>()
        val contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
        val projections = arrayOf(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE)

        context.contentResolver.query(contentUri,projections,null,null,null).use {
                cursor->
            if(cursor!=null && cursor.count > 0) {
                val idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID)
                val displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val typeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE)
                     fileCollection.clear()
                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    val id = cursor.getLong(idIndex)
                    val displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameIndex)
                    val type = cursor.getString(typeIndex)
                         fileCollection.add(AllFiles(id,displayName,type))
                }
            }
            else if(cursor==null)
                    Log.d("myTag","cursor is nUll")
            else
                    Log.d("myTag","Cursor count is ${cursor.count}")

        }
        fileCollection
    }
}
```

To run above method on android 12 , we need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

outside of onCreate

```
    val intent = Intent(ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION,
        Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID))

    val storagePermissionResultLauncher = 
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) {
        if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
            // Permission granted.
         getData()
        }
    }
```

and inside onCreate

```
if(!Environment.isExternalStorageManager())
        storagePermissionResultLauncher.launch(intent)
    else
        getData()
```

where  getData() is

```
fun getData(){
        val textview = binding.textviewFirst
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
            textview.append(getAllFiles(requireContext()).toString())
        }
    }
```

and AllFile is

```
data class AllFiles(
    val fileId : Long,
    val displayName : String?,
    val type : String?)
```

you can then filter returned list on type

Comment: Thanks. Removing the selections(setting it to null) gets all the file types! Totally forgot about that. I figure making the selection = `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE + ">=3072"` will filter according to my desired file size(3072).   Will the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE be accepted by Google play for a file sharing app(something like SHAREit)?

Comment: I have no idea about google play policies yet as I am beginner.

Comment: @lanezalbryt Yes, it should be accepted as to be used in a File sharing app. However, read the policies carefully & then go for it.